# Merge pdf files page size

Tags: c#, itext7

I merge pdf files using itext7 PdfMerger,
but page size is copied from the source file. - so each page has different size - according to the original size.
I would like the page size to be equal across the merged output file.  (i.e. A4 rotate)

```
 using(var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
   var pdfCombined = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(ms));
   var merger = new PdfMerger(pdfCombined);

   using(var pdfStream = file.OpenReadStream()) {

     var pdfReader = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(pdfStream));

     merger.Merge(pdfReader, 1, pdfReader.GetNumberOfPages());
     pdfReader.Close();
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Resize(Stream original, Stream stream)
    {
        original.Position = 0;
        stream.Position = 0;
        var orig = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(original));
        var pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(stream));
        pdf.GetWriter().SetCloseStream(false);
        var doc = new Document(pdf, PageSize);

        var pageSize = orig.GetPage(1).GetPageSizeWithRotation();

        var pageWidth = pageSize.GetWidth();
        var destWidth = PageSize.GetWidth();

        if (pageWidth > destWidth)
        {

            var transformationMatrix = AffineTransform.GetScaleInstance(
                pageWidth / destWidth / 2,
                pageSize.GetHeight() / PageSize.GetHeight() / 2);

            for (int i = 1; i <= orig.GetNumberOfPages(); i++)
            {
                var page = orig.GetPage(i);
                var formXObject = page.CopyAsFormXObject(pdf);
                var canvas = new PdfCanvas(pdf.AddNewPage(PageSize));
                canvas.ConcatMatrix(transformationMatrix);
                canvas.AddXObjectAt(formXObject, 0, 0);
            }

            doc.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This drops all interactive features.

Comment: @mkl so what are the best practices?

Comment: Please take my comment as what it is, a mere comment. As long as you don't have interactive features, doing it that way is ok. A complete solution also taking all interactive features into account is non-trivial. In addition to scaling the page you have to correct coordinates of annotations and of link destinations. And probably you even have to parse embedded JavaScript, understand what it does, and update it accordingly, too. So, clearly non-trivial.